# Refreezing bottled juice

Tags: freezing

I have a bottle of grape juice. I want to freeze the juice to extend the life of the juice. After thawing, can the juice be refrozen without ruining the juice?

Comment: Is the juice freshly pressed/squeezed/processed, or from concentrate?

Comment: Why was my question how long does it need to keep deleted?  To me that is a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

Me think the juice will lose some of its taste.

Instead of freezing the whole bottle, try freezing smaller portions so you only thaw portions as you need them.

You could use "Ziplock" type freezer bags, or small plastic or glass containers  to portion the juice in smaller quantity.